# Can I hide a part of a route?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an AppController and an AccountController. The AppController only has one view, `index`, which takes query string parameters from the `id` part of the url.

The default route is as follows: `{controller}/{action}/{id}` 
This means for the query string parameters to work properly, the view name has to be in the url. `url/view/id`

I would like to hide that part of the url and render that view by default, so users need only go to `url/id`.

I have tried `{controller}/{id}` and `{controller}/index/{id}` but neither work.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Done correctly.. they will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work. Set the url as : `"{controller}/{id}"` and give it a default action parameter:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: This worked exactly as intended. I thought I had tried this, apparently not.

Comment: The only problem with this, is that all my javascript seems to be broken since the change, any ideas?

Comment: Can you give an example? Also I think it's better to post a new question with it.

Comment: Will do, I'll see if I can sort it tonight, if not I'll post in the morning, thanks for your help!